# What is the back arrow "<-" in Golang?

Tags: go

I used it in a small piece of code to make `time.After()` work, without it the program simply goes on to the next line without waiting for the timer to finish.

This is the example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    a := 1
    fmt.Println("Starting")
    <-time.After(time.Second * 2)
    fmt.Println("Printed after 2 seconds")
}
```

Comment: This is the channel receive/send operator. Please take the tour of Go to learn the basics of the language, particularly the section on [channels](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2).

Comment: A `<-` appearing on the left of a channel expression corresponds to a receive operation on that channel. `time.After` is a function that returns a (receive-only) channel.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `<-` operator is used to wait for a response of a channel. It is used in this code to wait for a channel provided by the `time.After` that will be fed after X amount of time.

You can know more about channels in [the tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2) that @Marc mentioned. And note that `<-time.After(time.Second * 2)` can be replaced with the synchronous `time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)` statement, if you're not dealing with multiple channel results (with as `select`).

The `time.After` is usually used when timing out a result from a asynchronous operation involving one or more channels, something like this:

```golang
func doLongCalculations() (int, error) {
    resultchan := make(chan int)
    defer close(resultchan)

    go calculateSomething(resultchan)

    select {
    case <-time.After(time.Second * 2):
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("operation timed out")
    case result := <-resultchan
        return result, nil
    }
}
```

Again, we highly recommend you to take the tour of Go to get to know Go's basics :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Gustavo! I changed my code to use `time.Sleep()` that makes more sense to my use case where no extra channels are used.